# bundle 'com.microsoft.libSkiaSharp' Asset validation failed (90034) during MAUI App Submission with Transport

Tags: app-store, publish, maui

I publish a maui app with the console command

```
dotnet publish -f:net6.0-ios -c:Release /p:ServerAddress=192.168.xx.xxx /p:ServerUser=<name>/p:TcpPort=58181 /p:ArchiveOnBuild=true /p:_DotNetRootRemoteDirectory=/Users/<name>/Library/Caches/Xamarin/XMA/SDKs/dotnet/
```

and this creates an IPA file successfully. However, when I try to upload this file using Transport via a Macbook, I get the following error:

```
Asset validation failed (90034)
Missing or invalid signature. The bundle 'com.microsoft.libSkiaSharp' at bundle path 'Payload/Istanbul Bridge Conference Application.app/Frameworks/libSkiaSharp.framework' is not signed using an Apple submission certificate. (ID: da574c8d-9ef0-42a9-b7a8-05dfc6df8b41)
```

In my research I have seen that there are several questions with `Asset validation failed (90034)` but in all those the asset was the application itself. In my case a Microsoft library is causing problems. The definition of the library says it is multiplatform including iOS, so is this error because of my certificate or microsoft's? Is there anything that can be done to fix the problem?

Comment: It looks like `skiasharp lib` cause the problem ,kindly remove the package from dependences if you do not use the library in your project and see if problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same problem since the update to Visual Studio for Mac 17.x.

My solution is to copy the file, "Assets.car", from an old archive (built with the old version of Visual Studio) to the new release.

I know that this only fixes the symptom and not the reason, but it helps to get the app into the App Store.